# Draw and fill custom shape

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom shape using  the Path object in Android and I'm running into a weird problem.
What I'm trying to achieve is depicted in the picture below

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to draw and fill the shape:

```
 public class BallView extends RelativeLayout {
     ....
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      ...
      PaintArc(canvas);
     }

    private void PaintArc(Canvas canvas) {
     Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     p.setAntiAlias(true);
     p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
     p.setStrokeWidth(2);
     p.setColor(Color.RED);


     RectF oval = new RectF(20, 20, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
     RectF oval2 = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
     Path path = new Path();
     path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

     path.addArc(oval, 0, 180);
     path.addArc(oval2, 0, 180);

     float y=20+oval.height()/2;
     float x=20;
     path.moveTo(x,y);
     path.lineTo(x - 20, y);

     x=oval.width()+20;
     path.moveTo(x,y);
     path.lineTo(x+20,y);


     path.close();

     canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    } 
 }
```

The actual result that I'm getting looks like  this:

[image]

The resulting shape without Filling looks like this:

[image]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong  ?

Comment: why so complex? you can do what you want with one Path.addArc

Comment: I thought about making  the shape from just one arc and increasing the size of the line , but I'm just  experimenting and trying to  understand the framework. I want to know  how to fill a custom shape  built using  the Path object.

Comment: ok, i see, maybe try arcTo instead of addArc ?

Comment: Unfortunateley that doesn't work either. I initially thought the  path was not closed  and, by default, when I "paint" it using the fill style, the system automatically closes the  shape and I end up with  a semi-circle. But that is not the case.  The third image is a result of drawing the shape using a Paint with stroke style on a closed path and clearly  the path doesn't look like a semi-circle. I just don't understand why the interior of the shape  doesn't get filled and instead why the whole semi-circle gets filled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
class MyView extends View {

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private RectF mOval;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        mOval = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        int dx = w / 4;
        mOval.set(0, 0, w, w);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, w / 2f);
        mPath.arcTo(mOval, 180, 180);
        mPath.rLineTo(-dx, 0);
        mOval.inset(dx, dx);
        mPath.addArc(mOval, 0, -180);
        mPath.rLineTo(-dx, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        canvas.translate(0, getWidth() / 2);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey pskink. Thank you for the reply and sample. It seems to be happy now, but I don't really understand why. As far as I can see the shapes produced by both code samples are closed and they should be filled the same why. For some reason  your sample works and mine doesn't. I'll try to dig a little more and  come back if I find anything.

Comment: @Andrei was it anything to do with vertex ordering? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
- I have just edited my answer    
  and i add below code
```

> RectF oval3 = new RectF(10, 20, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);

/**
    *Now check this code output seem like your thought
   */

```
    private void PaintArc(Canvas canvas) {
          Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      p.setAntiAlias(true);
      p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      p.setStrokeWidth(2);
      p.setColor(Color.RED);

      Paint p1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      p1.setAntiAlias(true);
      p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      p1.setStrokeWidth(10);
      p1.setColor(Color.RED);

    RectF oval = new RectF(20, 20, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
    RectF oval2 = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    RectF oval3 = new RectF(10, 20, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    path.addArc(oval, 0, 180);
    path.addArc(oval2, 0, 180);
    path.addArc(oval3, 0, 180);


    float y = 20 + oval.height() / 2;
    float x = 20;
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    path.lineTo(x - 20, y);

    x = oval.width() + 20;
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    path.lineTo(x + 20, y);

    path.close();
    canvas.drawArc(oval3, 0, 180, false, p1);

    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Max. Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that won't help me. By changing the style to stroke  I will get the  result in the third image. What I want is  the result in the first image(that was made in paint)

Comment: Hi Max. Thank you for  the sample and the explanations. Unfortunately this still doesn't answer my question. The image i sent  might not have been the best example. What  I want is to fill that shape, I don't want the white borders. As I mentioned to  pskink, I know  I could probably  make  that curve using the stroke style with a larger thickness, but I want to fill a custom shape  built with the Path object. I wanted to know if that is possible and if so what is wrong with my approach.