# Drawing scalable shapes in Android

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-canvas

I need to draw a cross shape like below image, i have fixed set of points to draw,

```
                Path path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(133.133f, 45.7109f);
                path.lineTo(154.307f, 24.5363f);
                path.lineTo(175.482f, 45.7109f);
                path.lineTo(154.307f, 66.8856f);
                path.lineTo(175.482f, 88.0603f);
                path.lineTo(154.307f, 109.235f);
                path.lineTo(133.133f, 88.0603f);
                path.lineTo(111.958f, 109.235f);
                path.lineTo(90.7835f, 88.0603f);
                path.lineTo(111.958f, 66.8856f);
                path.lineTo(90.7835f, 45.7109f);
                path.lineTo(111.958f, 24.5363f);
                path.lineTo(133.133f, 45.7109f);
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Output

[image: Output of the above code]

Working fine upto this,

My Requirement is to scale this shape to various size, i have tried to scale the whole view, but the other elements which is drew in the same canvas was effected. Could you please suggest me the right way to archive this?

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, you need to define the points, lines, polygons etc. as parameters, so that you can scale and find the exact points with respect to the scale. If you want to find a faster way to do it, you probably need to find a way to convert your shapes to vector graphics and find a library to draw them onto your canvas.

Comment: see Path.transform method

Comment: Working great @pskink, also i have another issue when scale, it is transformed even i am not transform in matrix, code matrix.setScale(1f, 1f);
                path.transform(matrix);

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I means, the image should be enlarge from center point of the image, instead translate right or bottom.

Comment: so use the correct Matrix then

Comment: You can read these, might help (not sure) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002795/draw-and-fill-cutsom-shape?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980419/drawing-custom-shape-onto-canvas-in-android?rq=1